# I need to create a docker-compose for flask and several other libraries?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I need to create a docker-compose file for flask based API back end application. But this application is based on several other libraries following. All need to run on docker containers only. Can you suggest how will be the docker-compose file and related if any?

- psycopg2
- aniso8601==8.0.0
- argon2-cffi==19.2.0
- certifi==2019.11.28
- cffi==1.14.0
- chardet==3.0.4
- click==7.1.1
- cryptography==2.9
- defusedxml==0.6.0
- Flask==1.1.2
- Flask-Caching==1.8.0
- Flask-JWT-Extended==3.24.1
- Flask-Login==0.4.1
- Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.5
- Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
- Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
- Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
- flask-swagger==0.2.13
- Flask-WTF==0.14.3
- graphviz==0.14
- gunicorn==19.10.0
- idna==2.9
- itsdangerous==0.24
- Jinja2==2.10.1
- kazoo==2.5.0
- Mako==1.1.2
- MarkupSafe==1.1.1
- oauthlib==2.1.0
- passlib==1.7.2
- pika==1.1.0
- pycparser==2.20
- PyJWT==1.7.1
- pykafka==2.8.0
- pymemcache==3.1.1
- pymongo==3.5.1
- pypyodbc==1.3.5.2
- python-dateutil==2.8.1
- python-editor==1.0.4
- python3-openid==3.1.0
- pytz==2019.3
- PyYAML==5.3.1
- redis==3.5.0
- requests==2.23.0
- requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
- six==1.14.0
- SQLAlchemy==1.3.15
- SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.36.3
- tabulate==0.8.7
- urllib3==1.25.8
- Werkzeug==0.15.3
- WTForms==2.2.1
- python-ldap

Comment: Docker Compose is not really related to the contents of your `requirements.txt` file.  Your Python application shouldn't care whether it's running in Docker or not, much less whether Compose is managing it; Compose doesn't know what's in the containers it's running.

Answer (score 0):

My example is with Django but you can use for your flask container too

You can create a Dockerfile, for example if your flask container run within app folder of the container:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "${WEB_HOST}:${WEB_HOST}"
    depends_on:
      - mysql # if you have database in another container
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${WEB_HOST} #or what command you use to start your flask server
```

You need a requirements.txt file to list all your packages

And write a `Dockerfile` to install all package into app container folder when run docker-compose up:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-buster
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please don't edit into the wrong answer @Mani, the purpose of `ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt` is to add requirement.txt to the container  folder so it can run install in the container itself

Comment: Eventhough it's debatable I agree, But here adding requirements.txt doesn't make sense after dependency installation, as it is retained even after installing pip requirements and does nothing during runtime. As per building efficient images you are supposed to keep only the required things to run an image. So either u can add requiremennts.txt file -> use pip install -> remove requirements -> add /app or the proposed instructions be followed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way here is to go through this file - https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/. But if you want to try it fast, then here is some short instructions:

1. create a **requirements.txt** file with all dependencies (list of libs with versions)
2. create a **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /code

ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

3. create **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Of course in reality it will be more complex (you will have Data Base, maybe Redis, etc - for big project this tool can help you https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask)

Comment: But are all lib installing into directly or in docker container?

Comment: At docker container